Is there a way to transfer code from GBK to UTF8 by using Gitlab or other auto tanslation tools?
I'm working on a cross-platform program that needs to run on both Linux and Windows. However, I've encountered an encoding issue with Chinese characters after pulling some code from GitLab on Windows. The original code uses UTF-8, but I need to convert it to GBK on Windows due to specific compilation requirements.
Is there a way to automatically convert files from UTF-8 to GBK during the GitLab pull process, such as using a GitLab Runner or some other tool?

